# simplexml_load_file to file creating an empty file

Tags: php, xml

I'm taking an XML file from Amazon and trying to save it to a file.

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($signedUrl);
    $file = "c:/wamp/www/products.xml";
    file_put_contents($file, $xml);
```

This creates an empty file. Why?

Comment: `$xml` isn't empty itself right?

Comment: did you try to use json?

Comment: I can create some dummy text and it works, i.e. `$blah = "blah";`, it's the XML object that seems to be the problem

Comment: @aizele how would that help? Amazon returns XML

Comment: ahmm,, because I also tried that error ,,,, when I try something like this one..... "$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input') ,true)"  and afterwards I echo json_encode($data); it works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file()` itself returns an object on success, not a string, while `file_put_contents()` as a second argument expects a string to be written.

So you're trying to save an object instead of raw string.

In this scenario you can simply do something like this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($signedUrl);
$file = "c:/wamp/www/products.xml";
file_put_contents($file, $xml);
```

Since you merely want to save a response into a file.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter of `file_put_contents`  can be either a string, an array or a stream resource. `$xml` is an object!

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that. Thanks!